# How to create a new VM with a HDD os disk using Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I want to choose HDD os disk for a new VM to be deployed. I have tried using "New-AzDisk" "Set-AzVMOSDisk" and "New-AzVM"  powershell commands but got an error :
 `New-AzVM : Cannot attach an existing OS disk if the VM is created from a platform, user or a shared gallery image.
ErrorCode: InvalidParameter
ErrorMessage: Cannot attach an existing OS disk if the VM is created from a platform, user or a shared gallery image.
ErrorTarget: osDisk
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
OperationID : e7cac0e6-2ed8-4a61-a4ef-0bd04590b935
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rg_name -Location $location -VM $vm_adfs ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError : (:) [New-AzVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand`

my code is the following

```
    $diskconfig = New-AzDiskConfig -Location $location -DiskSizeGB 127 -AccountType Standard_LRS -OsType Windows -CreateOption Empty
    $disk = New-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $rg_name -DiskName $vm_name -Disk $diskconfig  
    $vm = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $vm_name -VMSize "Standard_DS1_V2"
    $vm = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm_adfs -ManagedDiskId $disk_adfs.Id -CreateOption Attach -Windows
    $vm = Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Windows -ComputerName $vm_name -Credential $vm_cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
    $vm = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
    $vm = Set-AzVMSourceImage -VM $vm_adfs -PublisherName 'MicrosoftWindowsServer' -Offer 'WindowsServer' -Skus '2016-Datacenter' -Version latest
    New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rg_name -Location $location -VM $vm -Verbose
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to create a VM with HDD os disk type from a VM image, but your code attempt to attach an existing os disk. I think it's the problem that caused the error. So the solution for you is that change the command:

```
$vm = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm_adfs -ManagedDiskId $disk_adfs.Id -CreateOption Attach -Windows
```

into:

```
$vm = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm_adfs -StorageAccountType Standard_LRS -CreateOption Attach -Windows
```

Or if you want to attach the existing OS disk to your new VM, then you just need to delete the command:

```
$vm = Set-AzVMSourceImage -VM $vm_adfs -PublisherName 'MicrosoftWindowsServer' -Offer 'WindowsServer' -Skus '2016-Datacenter' -Version latest
```

You cannot create a new VM from the VM image while attaching another existing OS disk to it. These two means will conflict when you use both of them at one time.

Comment: Thanks Charles Xu, I have used the first option. But had changed just one option "-CreateOption Attach" to "-CreateOption FromImage" otherwise it will not work

Comment: @maatougwassim No matter, you can choose any solution as you need.